# How to read specific range of columns and rows in xlsx doc with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a complex excel document. I want to read rows 76-102 range and A-G columns. I am using pandas. How can I do that?

```
import pandas as pd


def print_hi():
    df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='Scoring', )
   ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use two additional arguments -

usecols = Here, you can specify the range of columns you wanna use.

skiprows = Here, you can specify the function to skip rows.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Sample.xlsx', usecols= 'A:G', skiprows= lambda x: x<76 or x >102)
```